# For loop, if element does not equal value, replace with empty string

Tags: python, string, list, replace, equals

```
my_list = ['1 ab ac bbba','23 abcba a aabb ab','345 ccc ab aaaaa']
```

I'm trying to get rid of the numbers and the spaces, basically everything that's not an 'a','b', or 'c'

I tried this but it didn't work and I'm not sure why:

```
for str in my_list:
    for i in str:
        if i != 'a' or 'b' or 'c':
            i = ''
        else:
            pass
```

I want to eventually get:

```
my_list2 = ['abacbbba','abcbaaaabbab','cccabaaaaa']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace everything that is not `a`, `b`, or `c`, i.e., `[^abc]`, with an empty string:

```
import re
my_list2 = []
for str in my_list:
    my_list2.append(re.sub("[^abc]", "", str))
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/yR9vJ)**.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how `or` works:

```
if i != 'a' or 'b' or 'c':
```

is equivalent to

```
if (i != 'a') or ('b') or ('c'):
```

and will therefore always be `True` (because `b` evaluates to `True`).

You probably meant to write

```
if i != 'a' and i != 'b' and i != 'c':
```

which can also be written as

```
if i not in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
```

or even (since a string can iterate over its characters)

```
if i not in 'abc':
```

But even then, you're not doing anything with that information; a string is immutable, and by assigning `''` to `i`, you're not changing the string at all. So if you want to do it without a regex, the correct way would be

```
>>> my_list = ['1 ab ac bbba','23 abcba a aabb ab','345 ccc ab aaaaa']
>>> new_list = [''.join(c for c in s if c in 'abc') for s in my_list]
>>> new_list
['abacbbba', 'abcbaaaabbab', 'cccabaaaaa']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  m = ['1 ab ac bbba','23 abcba a aabb ab','345 ccc ab aaaaa']
  n=[m[x][m[x].index(" "):] for x in range(len(m))]
  n=[x.replace(" ","") for x in n]
```